# Why do message boxes not work as modal dialogs when created using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, modal-dialog, dispatcher

I've managed to create asynchronous modal dialogs using a combination of `Task.Run()` and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            MessageBox.Show("Modal dialog on same thread. " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            // Why do these two seem to behave the same despite Task.Run() using a different thread?
            Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("Attempted modal dialog on different thread using Task.Run(). " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Attempted asynchronous modal dialog on same thread using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(). " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)));

            // This behaves as desired.
            Task.Run(() => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Attempted modal dialog from different thread using Task.Run() AND Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(). " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))));

            // These are unreliable. They behave as desired when they're the only dialog shown.
            Task.Run(() => context.Send(state => MessageBox.Show("Attempted synchronous modal dialog on same thread using SynchronizationContext.Send(). " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId), null));
            Task.Run(() => context.Post(state => MessageBox.Show("Attempted asynchronous modal dialog on same thread using SynchronizationContext.Post(). " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId), null));
        }
    }
}
```

When using just `Task.Run()`, the dialog isn't modal. That is to say the main window can still receive focus while the dialog is open. Using just `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` has the same behavior. Why is that? Why wouldn't the dialog be modal if it's created on the main UI thread? And why would it work correctly when it's called from a different thread?

Furthermore, why wouldn't `SynchronizationContext.Post()` work the same as `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`, seeing as `DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Post()` just calls `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`?

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherSynchronizationContext.cs,b0fe97eb4a42faff

> ```
>     /// <summary>
>     ///     Asynchronously invoke the callback in the SynchronizationContext.
>     /// </summary>
>     public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
>     {
>         // Call BeginInvoke with the cached priority.  Note that BeginInvoke
>         // preserves the behavior of passing exceptions to
>         // Dispatcher.UnhandledException unlike InvokeAsync.  This is
>         // desireable because there is no way to await the call to Post, so
>         // exceptions are hard to observe.
>         _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_priority, d, state);
>     }
> ```

I would appreciate it if anyone can shed some light on this or point out anything I'm missing. In case you're wondering, the reason I need to create modal dialogs asynchronously is because I need to not block the UI thread because the code is actually being called from the ActionScript running in an `AxShockwaveFlash` control and it throws script timeout errors if it thinks it's executing for a long time.

Comment: I would question as to why a modal needs to be asynchronous.  I usually leave UI tasks on the UI thread and make the data being loaded into the modal async.  So the modal is quick and the long running tasks are completely separate and asynchronous.

Comment: I won't do such tests in `Window` *constructor*.

Comment: @DavidLee, I need to open the modal dialog after the current UI job has completed and returned control back to ActionScript  What is that called on the UI thread? When `BeginInvoke()` is used to add a delegate to the queue, is that a task or what?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I am having trouble understanding your use case.  when i use modals i open them asap then do all the other stuff after.  if its a really long task i use a loader in my modal till its complete.

Comment: This code suffers from a standard threading bug, it has a race condition.  MessageBox can only make itself modal by disabling other windows owned by the thread.  But it runs too soon here, before the UI thread had a chance to call Show() and create the window.  The Load event would be the correct place for this code.

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev. I seem to have jumped the gun here. I should've thought of that. When I wait to execute this code then they all work correctly.

Comment: And thanks @HansPassant as well.

Comment: Sorry @DavidLee, my specific needs involve an extremely rare circumstance and I think you'd have to understand ActionScript's `ExternalInterface` functionality.to really get it. But suffice it to say that I need to open a modal dialog without immediately blocking the thread that opens it. I'm still wondering what the terminology is, though. When the UI thread has finished the code it was executing and is ready for more code, what is that called? Is that a task?

Comment: I suppose I could call it a delegate, a `DispatcherOperation`, or an event since it's in the event queue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591208(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks

Comment: @KyleDelaney I see, I have not used ActionScript before. Good luck!

Comment: The comment above from Hans addresses the specific code example given. Your code is subject to timing variations, and is essentially a simple "I failed to write the code correctly" bug. The right fix is to show the dialog elsewhere (e.g. in `Loaded` event handler). But there's not enough context in your question to understand why you didn't do that in the first place, nor what you really are trying to do.